# Matlab: Feather plot on non-horizontal axis

Tags: matlab, plot

Is it possible to draw a feather plot of inclined arrows, over a non-horizontal axis in Matlab? for instance, over a circle or other curve.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You want to use [`quiver`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quiver.html) and define the tails (`x` and `y`) and direction vectors (`dx` and `dy`)

```
t = linspace(0, 2*pi, 20);
x = cos(t);
y = sin(t);

dx = 0.25 * x;
dy = 0.25 * y;

q = quiver(x, y, dx, dy, 1);
```

[image]

You'll need to do a little math to come up with the exact positions and vectors based upon your problem but this should definitely be able to give you the desired result.